# Facing issue with populating next available known value to replace nulls using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have input data set as below.

I am trying to populate null values (year and quarter) with next available value for that year. This will help yearly data is completely available for the company.

Current data set:

[image]

Expected data set:

[image]

Any pointers on how I can achieve this?

Comment: `lead()` is supported on SQL Server.

Comment: let me check and try again, may be i missed somehting

Comment: rather than lead(), perhaps max(year) over (partition by company)   ... assuming you are looking at one year at a time.

Comment: How did you fill out the first line with `2015-Q2`? It could have been `2016-Q1`, or `2015-Q3`. Remember that rows do not have inherent ordering in relational databases.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: or min()..... but the question is a bit unclear about that....

Comment: @Luuk  Yup.  min() would be better  abc needs to be Q2.   In dark mode, are to see the image with transparent background.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Please explain it. Otherwise this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF YOU HAVE ONE YEAR**, otherwise you would need a column to determine sequence.

**If Looking to SELECT**

```
Select company
      ,year    = coalesce(year,min(year) over (partition by company))
      ,Quarter = coalesce(quarter,min(quarter) over (partition by company))
 From  @YourTable
```

**If Looking to UPDATE**

```
Declare @YourTable table (company varchar(50), year int,quarter varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('abc',null,null)
,('abc',2015,'Q2')
,('abc',2015,'Q3')
,('pqr',null,null)
,('pqr',null,null)
,('pqr',2015,'Q3')

;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NYear = min(year) over (partition by company)
      ,NQtr  = min(quarter) over (partition by company)
 From @YourTable
)
Update cte
  set  Year   =NYear 
      ,Quarter=NQtr
 Where Year is null
```

**The Updated Table**

```
company year    quarter
abc     2015    Q2
abc     2015    Q2
abc     2015    Q3
pqr     2015    Q3
pqr     2015    Q3
pqr     2015    Q3
```

Comment: if we add partition by company and year, we can apply for all years.

Comment: @kumarkeshav No, because you have NULL years.   You would need a column which has the proper sequence so we could add an ORDER BY  in the over()

Comment: @kumarkeshav SQL Server has unordered data-sets.  Without an explicit ORDER BY there is no GTD of desired results.   A human can make that leap, but not SQL Server.